# How can i dynamically assign the props as variables to colors from my own color pallet in scss/css with react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am calling a component "MyRadioButton" with following props:

```
<MyRadioButton
          label="Radio Group"
          theme="custom-red"  //this line
          error="Field is required "
          radioBtns={options}
          id="radioBtns"
          name="radioBtns"
          getValue={this.getValue}
        />
```

I have created a react component "MyRadioButton" that will accept color name(theme) as props.

```
export const MyRadioButton = props => {
const {theme} = props;
return (
    <div className="my-radio-buttons"> // need to use theme here
      <input
              onChange={onChange}
              type="radio"   
       />
     </div>
)}
```

Based on this prop i want to assign the variable in my components scss file, which will take the color code from my custom defined color pallet.

my-radio-button.scss

```
/* custom color pallet */
  $custom-orange: #F060D6;
  $custom-red: #BB532E;
  $custom-blue: #4C9FEB;

.my-radio-buttons {
  .input{
     border: 2px solid $custom-red; // i want to assign the color variable based on input prop value to this property
   }
}
```

I have already tried setting variable at css root with javascript and accessing it with variable function var(),  it works fine.
But because of some limitations i dont want to use that approach.
also because the color pallet list is huge, i dont want to use separate classes for all of them.

I am looking for some other solution or different approach.

Comment: And using the style tag of the input is no option? The problem with using it in scss / css is that you may be able to read the color when your app starts, but I am highly sceptical that it will work on subsequent updates, as the css files at that time are static.

Comment: This is not going to change at runtime, css will be static. I just want to give the options to developer while creating application.

Comment: I really think the approach with the css-variable is the best one. I mean you can update it onMount of the component with the passed theme. This really does not fit your use case?

Comment: @Gh05d how can i update it onMount with passed theme?and yes i cannot use style tag as the theme variable is been used at many places with overridings as well

Answer (score 1):

So you can use a combination of custom css variables and your passed *theme* property. In you css, you would define the basecolor of the border for example:

```
.my-radio-buttons {
  --theme-color: red;

  input {
     border: 2px solid var(--theme-color);
   }
}
```

This can be updated by your components via `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` with the passed theme:

```
const MyRadioButton = props => {
  const { theme } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const input = document.querySelector(".my-radio-buttons input");

    input.style.setProperty("--theme-color", props.theme);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="my-radio-buttons">
      <input />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Depending on your code style, you can replace the `querySelector` with a `ref`.